# PDF Generation dynamically

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am working on PDF generation dynamically, I have pdf template and I am creating the similar dynamically using ITextSharp,I am creating the pdf and returning base64 string to mobile app,which then convert the base64 to pdf.
The template is like this

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LDEB.jpg)

The footer's disclaimer and page number will appear in all pages of PDF file, and page number is dynamic too.
I have created it successfully, it is not exactly same as of the template, Is there any other way to generate PDF without ITextsharp?
Can I use crystal report or RDLC for this or any other,that fulfils my requirements.(dynamic page number,disclaimer and page in all pages and base64 string).
The content of center table can be multiple ,so the pdf can be of more then one pages.

The difference of generated pdf is that center's table width is going out,it should align with top two tables(I have 100% for three tables),there are other issues as well.

Answer (score -1):

Generating footer and header with `ItextSharp` is not native,

so you need to code it manually.

Here, is a good Example:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573907/Generating-PDF-using-ItextSharp-with-Footer-in-Csh